# Função nao retorna o valor que eu quero

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int calculo(int pontos, int placar1, int placar2);

int main()
{
    int c;
    int placar1, placar2;
    char bet1n[30], bet2n[30], bet3n[30], bet4n[30], bet5n[30];
    int bet1a = 0, bet1b = 0, bet2a = 0, bet2b = 0, bet3a = 0, bet3b = 0, bet4a = 0, bet4b = 0, bet5a = 0, bet5b = 0;
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, p4 = 0, p5 = 0;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de gols do primeiro time:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &placar1);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("Digite a quantidade de gols do segundo time:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &placar2);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("O placar do jogo foi %d a %d\n", placar1, placar2);

    printf("Apostador 1. Digite o seu nome:\n");
    gets_s(bet1n);

    printf("Apostador digite a quantidade de gols do primeiro time:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &bet1a);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("Apostador digite a quantidade de gols do segundo time:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &bet1b);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    calculo(p1, bet1a, bet1b);
    printf("%d", p1);   // aqui so retorna 0
    printf("Apostador 2. Digite o seu nome:\n");
    gets_s(bet2n);


    printf("Apostador 3. Digite o seu nome:\n");
    gets_s(bet3n);


    printf("Apostador 4. Digite o seu nome:\n");
    gets_s(bet4n);


    printf("Apostador 5. Digite o seu nome:\n");
    gets_s(bet5n);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int calculo(int pontos, int placar1, int placar2) {
    if (placar1 < placar2)
    {
        pontos = 10;
        if (placar1 == 0)
        {
            pontos = pontos + 5;
        }
        if (placar2 == 4)
        {
            pontos = pontos + 5;
        }
        return (pontos);
    }
    else {
        if (placar1 == 0)
        {
            pontos = pontos + 5;
        }
        if (placar2 == 4)
        {
            pontos = pontos + 5;
        }
        return (pontos);
    }
}
```

Comment: E o que é que você queria que retornasse?

Comment: O valor do pontos somados apos a condição

Comment: A função basicamente nao esta funcionando, em vez de p1 receber o valor dos pontos somados, ele esta recebendo 0

Comment: Sua função está definida para receber 3 inteiros como parâmetros mas você a esta invocando com um inteiro e duas strings além de desprezar o valor de retorno. Você está utilizando passagem de parâmetro por valor e portanto não alterará o valor da variável no programa chamador.

Comment: strings? mas bet1a e bet1b estao em int, e qual o meu erro no valor de retorno? sou iniciante, acredito que reveria retornar o valor dos pontos usando a variavel pontos.

Comment: Me confundi com os nomes das variáveis, mas você está desprezando o valor de retorno da função e portanto está imprimindo o valor com que a função foi chamada e que não é modificado pela função, que no caso é 0.

Comment: E como eu corrigo isso?

Comment: Coloque uma variável pra receber o valor de retorno da função cálculo

Answer (score 1):

É preciso alterar a declaração e o uso da função "calculo".

Opção 1:

```
int calculo(int, int);

int main()
{
  ....
  p1 = calculo(bet1a, bet1b);
  printf("%d", p1);
  ...
}

int calculo(int placar1, int placar2)
{
  int pontos = 0;

  if (placar1 < placar2)
  {
    pontos = 10;
    if (placar1 == 0)
    {
      pontos += 5;
    }
    if (placar2 == 4)
    {
      pontos += 5;
    }
    return pontos;
  }
  else {
    if (placar1 == 0)
    {
      pontos += 5;
    }
    if (placar2 == 4)
    {
      pontos += 5;
    }
    return pontos;
  }
}
```

Opção 2:

```
void calculo(int*, int, int);

int main()
{
  ....
  calculo(&p1, bet1a, bet1b);
  printf("%d", p1);
  ...
}

void calculo(int* pontos, int placar1, int placar2)
{
  if (placar1 < placar2)
  {
    *pontos = 10;
    if (placar1 == 0)
    {
      *pontos += 5;
    }
    if (placar2 == 4)
    {
      *pontos += 5;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (placar1 == 0)
    {
      *pontos += 5;
    }
    if (placar2 == 4)
    {
      *pontos += 5;
    }
  }
}
```

Além disso, provavelmente a lógica da função "calculo" está errada, já que em qualquer caso a função está sempre somando 5 à variável "pontos".

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, a logica estava certa na verdade, mas eu declarei p1 dentro da funcao e achei q o retorno seria o suficiente, mas fazer a opcao 1 deu certo, declarei uma variavel para receber o valor, muito obrigado mano